# How to generate secp256k1 signature using private key in HEX format

Tags: .net, bouncycastle, secp256k1

I am trying to sign the short message using the PostingKey from the Hive network. I am trying to use BouncyCastle but I am not able to initialise its signer, my (not so good code) look like that:

```
 public static class Signer
    {
        public static byte[] Sign(string message, byte[] privateKey)
        {
            var signer = new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Signers.ECDsaSigner(new HMacDsaKCalculator(new Sha256Digest()));
            var bigInt = new BigInteger(privateKey);
            var parameters = new ECPrivateKeyParameters(bigInt, new ECDomainParameters())
            signer.Init(false, parameters);


            var messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
            var signature = signer.GenerateSignature(messageBytes);

            return signature;
        }
    }
```

I most likely doing something (or everything) wrong.

The key looks like that: 5KN6ZfGZgH1puWwH1Nc1P8xyrFZSPHDw3WUP6iitsjCECJLrGBq
which is then encoded into 32 byte array.

I have example code which works in JavaScript but I have failed to get it running in C#

```
eosjs_ecc.sign("message", "key")
```

Edited:
SO I have managed to generate the signature which matches the size generated one in JavaScript but I am still not able to sing int o the dApp. I am using the Cryptography.ECDSA library now as it can generate the signature with recovery number, r and s in one call. The only issues is that the signature is different every time I make the call for the same values.

```
var buffer = Secp256K1Manager.SignCompressedCompact(message, privateKey);
var checksum = Ripemd160Manager.GetHash(buffer);
var signatureArray = buffer.Concat(checksum.Take(4)).ToArray();

var result = Base58.Encode(signatureArray);
return $"SIG_K1_{result}";
```

Comment: It seems to be raw Bitcoin-style key, i.e. Base58-encoded 256-bit binary of secp256k1 secret key's d (see https://hive.blog/bitcoin/@aniqtariq/private-and-public-keys-explained).

Comment: it is that, any idea how can I create BouncyCastle PrivateKey class from it ?